# How to Show a Social Network in the ShareMediaTask on Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am in the process of taking screenshots for an app I developed, but I am having a lot of problems trying to figure out how to show more options than the default ShareMediaTask options in the WP8 emulator. Is there a way to do this? I'd like to be able to show something like Twitter as well, exactly as how it would look on the device. I can use my device only for a few languages supported since I purchased it in the United States, but some languages I require are not supported. Therefore, my ShareMediaTask screenshot (on the screen where you choose your share option) in the emulator can display all languages (with no social network) or on my device I can show the social network option but only with a few languages. Is there ANY way to either add an account to the emulator for screenshot purposes or add more display languages to my developer unlocked device?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot add an account to the emulator, your only hope is to load it on a real device. Maybe you could use [Nokia Remote Device Access for that](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access).